# How can I run a Python script in Azure DevOps with Azure Resource Manager credentials?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I have a Python script I want to run in Azure Resource Manager context within an Azure DevOps pipeline task to be able to access Azure resources (like the Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell tasks).

How can I get Azure RM Service Endpoint credentials stored in Azure DevOps passed - as ServicePrincipal/Secret or OAuth Token - into the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you call a python script, but either way Azure DevOps hasn't got native support to authenticate python sdk (or your custom python script), but you can pass in credentials from build\release variables to your script, or try and pull that from the Azure Cli (I think it stores data somewhere under `/home/.azure/`.

Comment: A good hint. Thanks. I'm trying with an ```Azure CLI``` task, an Windows batch inline script ```python "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\anyscript.py" "%USERPROFILE%\.azure\accessTokens.json"``` and parse the file in the PY script. Still struggling because the authorization for the management endpoint does not work - but that could be an unrelated problem.

Comment: that is an unrelated problem :)

Comment: Strange - I get a ```requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/...``` with the token stored by CLI. Have to check the scope.

Comment: you should raise a new question for that and consider accepting this one as an answer ;)

Comment: not yet ;-) accessTokens.json contains a 56 digit accessToken and not a OAuth / Bearer token I need

Comment: you need to use azure cli step, not just bash step. i see valid tokens in this file after i auth. as soon as I delete the file, i need to relogin. as soon as I login its populated with a token

Comment: I use an Azure CLI step - but the content in the file has the format ```[{"servicePrincipalId": "xxxx", "servicePrincipalTenant": "yyyy", "accessToken": "zzzz"}]```

Comment: in that case you probably need to revert to handling auth in the script

Comment: Azure CLI task logs in with a Service Principal, hence format of accessToken.json is different when doing a login with a common user

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly, you want to use the Python Azure CLI wrapper classes to manage or access Azure resources.  Rather than using shell or PowerShell commands.  I ran across the same issue and used the following steps to solve it.

[image]

```
import sys
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential    
tenant_id = sys.argv[1]
client_id = sys.argv[2]
client_secret = sys.argv[3]

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
```

1. Add a "User Python version" step to add the correct version of python to your agent's PATH
2. Add a "Azure CLI" step.  The goal here is to install your requirements and execute the script.
3. Within the Azure CLI step, be sure to check the "Access service principal details in script" box in the Advanced section.  This will allow you to pass in the service principal details into your script as arguments.
4. Pass in the $tenantId $servicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalKey variables as arguments.  These variables are pipeline defined so long as the box in step 3 is checked.  No action is required on your part to define them.
5. Setup your Python script to accept the values and setup your
   credentials.  See the script above

Comment: I was experimenting a little bit more today with this and noticed you don't even need to pass in the credentials.  You can use the AzureCliCredential class when running it in an Azure CLI Task and it will grab the session details

Comment: Also confirmed that credentials=AzureCliCredential() works as noted by NoPanicBanick without passing arguments to the script.  Going one step further, credentials= DefaultAzureCredential() also works.  This second approach tries many approaches until one works (and will eventually get to the AzureCliCredential().  See more at this post: https://bzzzt.io/post/2021-10/2021-10-07-many-ways-to-authenticate-python/

Answer (score 0):

based on the hint given by [4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41) above and with some dissecting of [Azure CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) I created this function that allows pulling an OAuth token over `ADAL` from the *Service Princial* logged in inside an *Azure DevOps - Azure CLI* task

```
import os
import json
import adal

_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID = 'servicePrincipalId'
_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_TENANT = 'servicePrincipalTenant'
_TOKEN_ENTRY_TOKEN_TYPE = 'tokenType'
_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'accessToken'

def get_config_dir():
    return os.getenv('AZURE_CONFIG_DIR', None) or os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.azure'))

def getOAuthTokenFromCLI():
    token_file = (os.environ.get('AZURE_ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE', None)
              or os.path.join(get_config_dir(), 'accessTokens.json'))

    with open(token_file) as f:
        tokenEntry = json.load(f)[0] # just assume first entry

    tenantID = tokenEntry[_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_TENANT]
    appId = tokenEntry[_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID]
    appPassword = tokenEntry[_ACCESS_TOKEN]
    authURL = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID
    resource = "https://management.azure.com/"
    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authURL, validate_authority=tenantID, api_version=None)
    token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource,appId,appPassword)
    return token[_TOKEN_ENTRY_TOKEN_TYPE] + " " + token[_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

Comment: How do you get that _ACCESS_TOKEN ? 

Can i use ADAL with a AAD app credentials like this to authenticate to azure devops?

Comment: @AnjanaDyna - I'm not sure but I guess there is no way around the PAT / personal access token when it comes to Azure DevOps.

Comment: Do you know how a new user could be added to azure devops? Using python client library or REST API? I asked this as a question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591886/how-to-add-a-user-to-azure-devops-using-its-python-client-api

But didn't got any answer yet.

Comment: @AnjanaDyna - I would use this REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0