# How to add a user to Azure DevOps using it's python client API?

Tags: python, api, azure-devops, client, azure-devops-rest-api

I am writing a python script to add a user(an existing user from the AAD backed provider) to Azure DevOps. I am using python client library of Azure DevOps for this purpose.
After authentication, I am able to fetch the users from azure devops as:

```
# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client (the "graph" client provides access to list,get and create user)
graph_client = connection.clients_v5_0.get_graph_client()
resp = graph_client.list_users()

# Access the properties of object as object.property
users = resp.graph_users

# Show details about each user in the console
for user in users:
    pprint.pprint(user.__dict__)
    print("\n")
```

How to add a user using this GraphClient connection?

There is a create_user function ( use as `graph_client.create_user()` ) here to do this: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_0/graph/graph_client.py

It says that the request should include a GraphUserCreationContext as an input parameter.

But how can I get that GraphUserCreationContext for an AAD user? I only have information about the AAD user's UPN as input.

**Note:**

I found .NET sample to do this here : https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/Graph/UsersSample.cs

It uses GraphUserPrincipalNameCreationContext which extends GraphUserCreationContext.

But i couldn't find such a class in python client library. I used the code like this:

```
addAADUserContext = GraphUserCreationContext('anaya.john@domain.com')
print(addAADUserContext)
resp = graph_client.create_user(addAADUserContext)
print(resp)
```

But got an error:

```
azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: VS860015: Must have exactly one of originId or principalName set.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GraphUserCreationContext` class from the python client for azure devops REST API accepts only one input parameter which is `StorageKey`. Hence, whatever you provide as an input parameter to that function, be it a UPN or ID, it is set as a storage key.

If you print the `addAADUserContext` object, you will get:

```
{'additional_properties': {}, 'storage_key': 'anaya.john@domain.com'}
```

But the `create_user()` function of Graph client needs exactly one of originId or principalName set in the `GraphUserCreationContext` it takes as input parameter.

As the microsoft documentaion for the azure devops REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1 ) :

> The body of the request must be a derived type of GraphUserCreationContext:
>
> - GraphUserMailAddressCreationContext
> - GraphUserOriginIdCreationContext
> - GraphUserPrincipalNameCreationContext

We shouldn't use the `GraphUserCreationContext` object directly. But the classes like GraphUserPrincipalNameCreationContext aren't currently available in the python client API. They are working on it. You can track the issue here in GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/issues/176

You can use User Entitlements - Add REST API for azure devops instead of it's Graph API. You can use the following python client for this purpose:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/tree/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_0/member_entitlement_management

You can refer to the sample given in the following question to know about how to use the mentioned python client :

[Unable to deserialize to object: type, KeyError: ' key: int; value: str '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665624/unable-to-deserialize-to-object-type-keyerror-key-int-value-str)

Answer (score 0):

I created this class using their Model

```
class GraphUserAADCreationContext(Model):
    """
    :param principal_name: The principal name from AAD like 'user@mydomain.com'
    :type principal_name: str
    :param storage_key: Optional: If provided, we will use this identifier for the storage key of the created user
    :type storage_key: str
    """
    
    _attribute_map = {
        'storage_key': {'key': 'storageKey', 'type': 'str'},
        'principal_name': {'key': 'principalName', 'type': 'str'}
    }

    def __init__(self, storage_key=None, principal_name=None):
        super(GraphUserAADCreationContext, self).__init__()
        self.storage_key = storage_key
        self.principal_name = principal_name
```

You can us instance of this class as input parameter instead of GraphUserCreationContext